# Return multiple matrices based on user input to function

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function that accepts user parameter k and generates a matrix of the form:

```
a = np.array((k,2,5))
```

Leaving the function I would like to return *k* 2x5 matrices. Essentially,

```
if k == 2:
  return a[0,:,:], a[1,:,:]
if k == 3:
  return a[0,:,:], a[1,:,:], a[2,:,:]
```

Is there a way to do this dynamically without having to hard-code each of the possible values of k?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
return tuple(a[i,:,:] for i in range(k))
```

Python's great!  8-))

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using [`np.array_split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) -

```
np.array_split(a[:k].reshape(-1,a.shape[-1]),k)shorter
```

Even shorter with [`np.vsplit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.1/reference/generated/numpy.vsplit.html) -

```
np.vsplit(a[:k].reshape(-1,a.shape[-1]), k)
```

---

Please note that if you are assigning the output from the relevant function to `k` number of outputs, you don't need all this mess and can simply return the slice . i.e. do : `return a[:k]`.

As an example :

```
In [595]: a = np.random.rand(4,2,5)

In [596]: k = 3

In [597]: a0,a1,a2 = a[:k]

In [598]: np.allclose(a0, a[0,:,:]) # Verify for all three outputs
Out[598]: True

In [599]: np.allclose(a1, a[1,:,:])
Out[599]: True

In [600]: np.allclose(a2, a[2,:,:])
Out[600]: True
```

Comment: Less readable but probably faster than the tuple comprehension. ⁺¹

Comment: @Alfe Yeah I am hoping it would be faster.

Comment: `a[:k]` works for me as I am assigning them like you mention; thanks.

Comment: @steeeve Glad to be of help on this!